# Why the equal sign is accepted between 'let' and name of the variable?

Tags: javascript

I accidentally wrote a weird declaration in my code

```
let = x = 5;
```

And it took me some time to actually notice it as it worked as expected (x was indeed 5).
I wanted to ask why is that? Is it interpreted similarly as

```
let y = x = 5;
```

(just with the missing second variable) or has it some other function? It bothered me since and I can't seem to find an answer

Comment: python variables are not declared. here `let` doesn't do the same as in javascript, so the line `let y = x = 5;` is incorrect. the first line is declaring `let` and `x` as variables and assigning the value 5 to both of them. If you just want a variable x with value 5 do `x = 5`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Sorry, my question was badly tagged. I was in fact asking about javascript code

Comment: Javascript apparently treats `let` as a "soft" keyword; it has special meaning if it precedes the assignment, but otherwise can be used as an identifier as *part* of the assignment.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Then please ask a new question. Retagging it now will invalidate all the given answers.

Comment: The answers aren't entirely invalidated; the same reasoning (more or less) applies to the behavior in Javascript.

Comment: Python --> Javascript --> Python. Which is it?!

Comment: @tdelaney It was Python, then people answered with explanations why it doesn't matter in Python, then OP changed it to JS invalidating the existing answers, which is why I rolled it back. But given that now all answers are for JavaScript, I guess we can stick with JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for backwards compatibility.

`let` was a valid *variable name* before the `let` *keyword* was added to the JavaScript language, and needs to remain so to avoid breaking old software.

```js
let = 5;
console.log(let);
```

This isn't the case for code running in strict mode (which I strongly advise using if at all possible).

```html
<script type="module">
let = 5;
console.log(let);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You assigned the value of 5 to both `let` and `x`:

```
let = x = 5;
console.log(let);
console.log(x);
// Outputs 5
// Outputs 5
```

However, this doesn't interfere with the `let` keyword, and it still works as per usual.